# SQL - results from 3 tables, aggregate functions

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am trying to create SQL query for below results:

```
id, name,   Users in group, Messages in groups, Message type 1 in groups, Message type 2 in groups
1   Group1  4               3                   2                         1
2   Group2  3               2                   1                         1
3   Group1  1               1                   1                         0
```

My database:

```
create database user_test;

use user_test;


CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id`             BIGINT      NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `group_id`       BIGINT      NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `user_group` (
  `id`      BIGINT           NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`    VARCHAR(100)
            CHARACTER SET utf8
            COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`name`) USING BTREE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


CREATE TABLE `message` (
  `id`               BIGINT   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id`           BIGINT   NOT NULL,
  `type`             INT      NOT NULL,
  `date`             DATETIME NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `unique` (`user_id`, `type`, `date`) USING BTREE,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);


ALTER TABLE user
    ADD CONSTRAINT user_group_c_fk FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES user_group(id);


ALTER TABLE message
    ADD CONSTRAINT user_a_fk FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(id);
```

And initial value:

```
INSERT INTO `user_group`
VALUES (1, "Group 1"),
       (2, "Group 2"),
       (3, "Group 3");

INSERT INTO `user`
VALUES (1, "User 1", 1),
       (2, "User 2", 1),
       (3, "User 3", 1),
       (4, "User 4", 1),
       (5, "User 5", 2),
       (6, "User 6", 2),
       (7, "User 7", 2),
       (8, "User 8", 3);

INSERT INTO `message`
VALUES (1, 1, 1, "2019-07-25 00:00:00"),
       (2, 1, 2, "2019-07-25 00:00:01"),
       (3, 1, 2, "2019-07-25 00:00:02"),
       (4, 5, 1, "2019-07-25 00:00:03"),
       (5, 6, 2, "2019-07-25 00:00:04"),
       (6, 8, 1, "2019-07-25 00:00:05");
```

I am wondering if it is possible results. I am trying with sth like this:

```
use user_test;

select user_group.id, 
       user_group.name,
       count(user.id) As "Users in group",
       count(message.id) AS "Messages in groups",
       count(message.type = 1) AS "Message type1 in groups",
       count(message.type = 2) AS "Message type2 in groups"
FROM user_group
LEFT JOIN user ON user.group_id = user_group.id
LEFT JOIN message ON message.user_id = user.id
WHERE user_group.id = message.user_id
GROUP BY user_group.id;
```

But, of course, it is totally wrong query. I think that configuration database is not help, in this situation, but it is small split with whole system, which I can't modify. I would like to create that one generic query for backend endpoint - the best solution will be one query for all result.

Comment: That `WHERE` clause looks very odd. You have the same condition in the ON clause already, but the WHERE will make the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result.

Comment: Oh true. I can't remove that WHERE clause... But the problem is still that same.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code, if available.

Comment: But first step is checking if I can generate that result in the database.

Comment: @RaymondNijland, perhaps a bit unclear, but note that I said _the_ WHERE clause, not _a_ WHERE clause.

Comment: yea i noticed it after writting mine comment and removed mine comment before you posted your comment @jarlh

Comment: i guess in message table have only 2 types one and two..then 4th column in the result would be the sum of 5th and 6th..Am i correct?

Comment: Messages in groups = message typ1 + message type2, yes, there is only two types of message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quick-and-dirty using `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT ug.id, ug.name,
       count(distinct u.id) As "Users in group",
       count(distinct m.id) AS "Messages in groups",
       count(distinct case when m.type = 1 then m.id end) AS "Message type1 in groups",
       count(distinct case when m.type = 2 then m.id end) AS "Message type2 in groups"
FROM user_group ug  LEFT JOIN
     user u
     ON u.group_id = ug.id LEFT JOIN
     message m
     ON m.user_id = u.id
WHERE ug.id = m.user_id
GROUP BY ug.id;
```

You can also get accurate counts by aggregating *before* doing the joins.  Also note that I added table aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps. 
I am doing Inner Join instead of left join. You can change if needed.

```
select 
ug.id, 
ug.name,
count(u.id) as users_in_group,
count(m.id) as messages_in_group,
count(decode(m.type,'1',count(m.id))) as message_type1_in_group, 
count(decode(m.type,'2',count(m.id))) as message_type1_in_group
from user_group ug
join user u on ug.id=u.group_id
join message m on m.user_id = u.user_id
group by ug.id,ug.name ug.id,ug.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit edit on Gordon Linoff's Answer.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS "Users in group" ,
       COUNT(c.id) AS "Messages in groups",
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.type = 1 THEN c.id END) AS "Message type 1 in groups",
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN c.type = 2 THEN c.id END) AS "Message type 2 in groups"
FROM user_group a LEFT JOIN
     USER b
     ON b.group_id = a.id LEFT JOIN
     message c
     ON c.user_id = b.id GROUP BY a.id;
```

Here aggregate results are fetched from grouped table.

Comment: Thank you for great add. info about query!

Answer (score 0):

I am really close to get the proper result! But still is not the correct one, but maybe help...

```
use user_test;

 select user_group.id, 
       user_group.name,
        count(user.id) As "Users in group",
        count(message.id) AS "Messages in groups",
        count(CASE message.type WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE null end) AS "Message type1 in groups",
        count(CASE message.type WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE null end) AS "Message type2 in groups" FROM user_group LEFT JOIN user ON
 user.group_id = user_group.id LEFT JOIN message ON message.user_id =
 user.id WHERE user_group.id = user.group_id GROUP BY user_group.id,
 message.type
```